# can't run "rails server" on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am just One hour new to ROR. I am getting trained by the "Lynda.com Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training". And after installing all the components, I am unable to start the web server. What I do is the following:-
////////////////////////This is what i get after i type "rails server" in command prompt /////////////

```
    port/descendants_tracker.rb
  415 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb
  416 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_reco
rd/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb
  417 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_reco
rd/scoping.rb
  418 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_reco
rd.rb
  419 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.5/lib/active_model
/railtie.rb
  420 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module/attr_internal.rb
  421 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module/anonymous.rb
  422 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/abstract_cont
roller.rb
  423 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispat
ch/http/filter_redirect.rb
  424 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/request.rb
  425 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/response.rb
  426 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispat
ch/http/cache.rb
  427 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispat
ch/http/response.rb
  428 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/json/decoding.rb
  429 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/json/encoding.rb
  430 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/json.rb
  431 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/live.rb
  432 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb
  433 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access.rb
  434 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/rescuable.rb
  435 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispat
ch/http/upload.rb
  436 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/mock_sess
ion.rb
  437 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/cook
ie_jar.rb
  438 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/mock
_digest_request.rb
  439 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/util
s.rb
  440 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/meth
ods.rb
  441 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/uplo
aded_file.rb
  442 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test.rb
  443 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/strong_parameters.rb
  444 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/load_error.rb
  445 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/name_error.rb
  446 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/uri.rb
  447 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_contro
ller.rb
  448 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/abstract_cont
roller/railties/routes_helpers.rb
  449 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_contro
ller/railties/helpers.rb
  450 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/g
em_version.rb
  451 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/v
ersion.rb
  452 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb
  453 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb
  454 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view.r
b
  455 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/r
ailtie.rb
  456 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_contro
ller/railtie.rb
  457 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_reco
rd/railtie.rb
  458 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.5/lib/action_mail
er/gem_version.rb
  459 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.5/lib/action_mail
er/version.rb
  460 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/class/delegating_attributes.rb
  461 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module/reachable.rb
  462 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/class/subclasses.rb
  463 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/class.rb
  464 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.5/lib/action_mail
er.rb
  465 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.5/lib/action_mail
er/railtie.rb
  466 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/test_unit
/railtie.rb
  467 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/ver
sion.rb
  468 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike.rb
  469 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb
  470 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/string.rb
  471 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/erb.rb
  472 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/etanni.rb
  473 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/haml.rb
  474 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/css.rb
  475 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/csv.rb
  476 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/coffee.rb
  477 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/nokogiri.rb
  478 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/builder.rb
  479 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/markaby.rb
  480 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/liquid.rb
  481 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/radius.rb
  482 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/markdown.rb
  483 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/textile.rb
  484 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/rdoc.rb
  485 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/wiki.rb
  486 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/yajl.rb
  487 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/asciidoc.rb
  488 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/plain.rb
  489 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt.rb
  490 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/eco
_template.rb
  491 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/ejs
_template.rb
  492 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/jst
_processor.rb
  493 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/uti
ls.rb
  494 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/eng
ines.rb
  495 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/mime.rb
  496 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/mim
e.rb
  497 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/pro
cessor.rb
  498 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/pro
cessing.rb
  499 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/com
pressing.rb
  500 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/pat
hs.rb
  501 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/normalized_arr
ay.rb
  502 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/extensions.rb
  503 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/index.rb
  504 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/paths.rb
  505 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/trail.rb
  506 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb
  507 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/syntax_error.rb
  508 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/psych.so
  509 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/node.rb
  510 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/stream.rb
  511 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/document.rb
  512 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/sequence.rb
  513 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/scalar.rb
  514 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/mapping.rb
  515 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/alias.rb
  516 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes.rb
  517 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/streaming.rb
  518 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb
  519 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb
  520 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb
  521 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/emitter.rb
  522 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb
  523 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/json/ruby_events.rb
  524 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/json_tree.rb
  525 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/depth_first.rb
  526 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors.rb
  527 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/handler.rb
  528 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/tree_builder.rb
  529 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/parser.rb
  530 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/omap.rb
  531 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/set.rb
  532 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/coder.rb
  533 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/core_ext.rb
  534 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/deprecated.rb
  535 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/stream.rb
  536 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/json/yaml_events.rb
  537 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/json/tree_builder.rb
  538 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/json/stream.rb
  539 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/handlers/document_stream.rb
  540 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb
  541 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb
  542 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/dir
ective_processor.rb
  543 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/saf
ety_colons.rb
  544 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/cha
rset_normalizer.rb
  545 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sas
s_compressor.rb
  546 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/yui
_compressor.rb
  547 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/clo
sure_compressor.rb
  548 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/ugl
ifier_compressor.rb
  549 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sas
s_template.rb
  550 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/scs
s_template.rb
  551 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets.rb
  552 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/benchmarkable.rb
  553 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/active_model_helper.rb
  554 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/asset_url_helper.rb
  555 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/capture_helper.rb
  556 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/tag_helper.rb
  557 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/asset_tag_helper.rb
  558 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/atom_feed_helper.rb
  559 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/cache_helper.rb
  560 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/controller_helper.rb
  561 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/csrf_helper.rb
  562 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/date_helper.rb
  563 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/debug_helper.rb
  564 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/javascript_helper.rb
  565 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/array/access.rb
  566 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/url_helper.rb
  567 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/string/filters.rb
  568 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/v
endor/html-scanner.rb
  569 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/sanitize_helper.rb
  570 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/output_safety_helper.rb
  571 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/text_helper.rb
  572 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/form_tag_helper.rb
  573 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/m
odel_naming.rb
  574 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/form_helper.rb
  575 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/form_options_helper.rb
  576 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/number_helper.rb
  577 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/number_helper.rb
  578 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module/concerning.rb
  579 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb
  580 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module.rb
  581 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/r
ecord_identifier.rb
  582 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/record_tag_helper.rb
  583 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/rendering_helper.rb
  584 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers/translation_helper.rb
  585 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.5/lib/action_view/h
elpers.rb
  586 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprocket
s/rails/helper.rb
  587 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprocket
s/rails/version.rb
  588 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine/co
nfiguration.rb
  589 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/applicati
on/configuration.rb
  590 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprocket
s/railtie.rb
  591 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/all.rb
  592 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/version.r
b
  593 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/error.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

C:\Users\bestacademyonline\Sites\simple_cms>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////End//////////////////////////////////////////

Please Help me guys, waiting for you guys!

Comment: use http://www.railsinstaller.org/en to install rails on windows

Answer (score 0):

check your cofig/database.yml file. your user and password for mysql installation should match with mentioned in database.yml.

If this is correct can you show me your gem file details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What i have done is That i installed "Bitnami Stack installer" and it worked for ME a new ROR user. So, thanks again. And I think this is the solution.